# hierarchical parameter transfer in generated blocks

Tags: verilog

I have 12 modules which I generate in a generate statement.

```
module top
genvar i;
generate
for(i=0;i<12;i=i+1) begin
LVDSser #(
    .FULL_FRAME(300),
    .ON_TIME(132),
    .OFF_TIME(168),
    .filename(FILE_NAME)
    )
 LVDSser_inst(
     .clk(clk),
     .rstn(rstn),
     .Ch(Ch[i]),
     .LVDSclk(clkArry[i]),
     .LVDSdata(dataArry[i])
    );
end
endgenerate
```

in this module I need to read a file with readmemh.

```
module LVDSser(
    input clk,
    input rstn,
    input[3:0] Ch,
    output LVDSclk,
    output[3:0] LVDSdata
    );

parameter filename = "test.txt"; 
reg[63:0] inputData [0:3];
initial $readmemh(filename,inputData);
endmodule
```

how can I generate an array to hold the file names?
for now I have to copy the instantiated module 12 times and write the unique file name for each module. (I can't use generate) 
thanks 
zahike

Answer (score 0):

You can in general pass the filename as a parameter when using generate in the top module. This might help you

[How to pass filename as a parameter](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/Verilog-read-from-file-to-parameters-in-module-initial-generate/td-p/418261)

Comment: Thanks I transferred the file name in to the module by parameter. the problem is that I have 12 modules like that so for now I instantiated each one individually and transferred the right file name for each one. I ask if there is a way to arrange the file_names as an array so I can use the generate command and not transfer each one individually.

Comment: Because links can rot over time, [it is expected that you summarize the essential information directly in your answer](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259), allowing the link to serve only as a reference. So, in this case, you would need to show/explain *how* you pass the file name as a parameter.